# Converting string to character array to int array to linkedlist

Tags: java

If I input a String like "-32323" my out put is [-50,-51,-50,-51,-50], and I am not sure where these values are coming from. The output I am trying to get is [-3,-2,-3,-2,-3]

```
static LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();

public static LinkedList<Integer> method(String s) 
{

        char[] listOfChar;
        int[] num;

        list = new LinkedList<Integer>();

        listOfChar = s.toCharArray();

        if (listOfChar[0] == '-') {
            num = new int[listOfChar.length - 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
                num[i] = -1 * listOfChar[i + 1];
            }
        }

        else {
            num = new int[listOfChar.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
                num[i] = listOfChar[i];
            }
        }

        for (Integer x : num) {
            list.push(x);
        }
        return list;

}
```

Comment: Google "ASCII chart".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**problem:**

```
listOfChar[i + 1];
```

It will convert your `char` to `decimal value` of it (ex. `char 3` is equals to `51`).

[click here](http://www.asciitable.com/) to know the decimal values of different characters

**solution:**

```
 num[i] = -1 * (listOfChar[i + 1] - '0');
```

You need to deduct `char 0` to make it `3`, because `char 0` in decimal is `48` which means (`51 - 48`) is equals to `3`.